# Interpretation of y-axis in partial dependence plot

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, scikit-learn, boosting

First off, I know there are many questions on this site similar to this one. I've read them, and have not been able to find a solution.

In *Elements of Statistical Learning*, the following figure shows partial dependence plots for California Housing Data:

[image: Meaning of y-axis in partial dependence plot]

The text defines partial dependence of $f(X)$ on $X_S$ as $f_S(X_S) = E_{X_C}f(X_S, X_C)$, the marginal average of $f$.

I'm wondering how to interpret the y-axis of these plots. Based on the definition, I would expect the y-axis to be the housing price, as the given x-axis variables vary, while accounting for the averages of all other variables. But that can't be the case, because the y-axis has negative values, and all values are in the range -1 to 2.

The scikit-learn documentation shows how to make the plots here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-partial-dependence-py.

Other questions have asked specifically about the implementation in R for classification, which uses a logit, and explains the negative values. But I'm wondering about the regression case, as described in *Elements*.

Comment: It is usually on the same scale as the values returned by `predict`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I've made a model GBM model on the Boston Housing set, and 'predict' returns prices of homes in $1000's. But the partial dependence plots also have negative values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we are seeing are changes relative to an overall central tendency. This is easy to miss. The central tendency used is a bit of the author's choice.

In [The Elements of
Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) (2009), the caption of Fig. 10.17 particular mentions: "*Partial dependence of median house value on location in California. One unit is \$100,000, at 1990 prices, and the values plotted are **relative to** the overall median of \$180,000.*" (emphasis mine).

Similarly in `scikit-learn` documentation in the "[*California Housing data preprocessing*](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html#california-housing-data-preprocessing)" we have the line: `y -= y.mean()`. This subtracts the mean target value from our target vector and centres our target variables to $0$; as a result our PDPs values will be centred approximately around $0$ too. (`sklearn`'s [`fetch_california_housing()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_california_housing.html) also states that the target is "*in units of 100,000*".)

In general, I prefer to show my PDPs uncentred at first instance because it makes it plainly clear how much (approximate) variability a particular feature has on the response but that is a matter of choice. As we see, Hastie et al. (2009) centred around the median, `sklearn` centred around the mean, while Friedman (2001) "[*Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1013203451)" (Fig. 11) did not centre at all. Similar to Friedman (2001), Greenwell (2017) "[*pdp: An R Package for Constructing Partial Dependence Plots*](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-016/index.html)" also does not centre by default (Fig. 2 and others).

Comment: Thank you for providing such a detailed answer! I especially appreciate the references to the sources from which I drew the question.

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help! :)